# Make Json parsable by php

Tags: php, javascript, json

I have some weirdly formatted json string which is invalid json, but executes as valid javascript. This means PHP `json_decode`, will not work.

```
{
  "Devices":{
    "Device1":"{ \"Name\"=\>\"AutoTap LDVDS\",\"ID\"=\>\"LDVDSDevice\"}"
  }
}
```

The backslashes are not valid. Is there some way I can escape this string so it can be re-encoded exactly the same as it came in?

**Edit** I don't care about parsing the messy string at all. It's preventing me from accessing other data. I *was* doing a simple regex to strip the ugly strings out of the json before parsing it. But now I need to re-encode the result array back into JSON and I want to avoid losing this data. The ugly string should remain exactly the same, as it may be important to some other application that uses this data.

The `=>` comes from ruby object notation in case you are wondering.

Comment: Why not fix the roots of issue instead?

Comment: I wish I could do this. Unfortunately I this is not data I control. It's in a large enterprise database and I would have to wait at least a couple of weeks before it can be fixed.

Comment: Ehm. The JSON is perfectly valid. It just happens to be container to a secondary non-JSON format as well. Use plain `json_decode` and a smallish parser for the contained `=>` string maps.

Comment: @mario Whether it's technically valid or not, `json_decode` doesn't like it.

Comment: Perhaps html characters like &#92; would be the best way to escape this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's those weird escaped `>` that are killing it: `\>`

I see no reason why you can't `str_replace` them out of existence safely with a simple:

```
<?php

$code='{
  "Devices":{
    "Device1":"{ \"Name\"=\>\"AutoTap LDVDS\",\"ID\"=\>\"LDVDSDevice\"}"
  }
}';

$code=str_replace('\\>','>',$code);

var_export(json_decode($code));
```

But then, **you know the domain of your data**.
And you should apply a *grain of salt* before applying that blindly to all your inputs.

Comment: You'd also need to replace `=>` with `:`

Comment: I was thinking about this, but I will leave it as a string. It might be a string instead of an object for some specific reason.

Comment: @Keyo, I would do the same. You can always parse that string later.

Answer (score 0):

You could run [stripslashes](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) on it, and then pass that sring into `json_decode`.

Comment: Device1 is a *string* here, and stripslashing it would wreak havoc.